# Create a selectInput() with maximum number of choices based on a numericInput()

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app:

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("book1")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               uiOutput("book10")
             )
           )))
#server.
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$book1<-renderUI({
    numericInput("bk1", 
                 "Items in test", 
                 value = 1,
                 min = 1)
  })
  output$book10<-renderUI({

    selectInput("bk10", 
                "Select Items", 
                choices=1:10000,multiple =T,selected = 1)
  })
}
```

In the sidebar I have a `numricInput()` which I want to use as limit for the number of choices displayed in the `selectInput()` in the main panel. For example if the `numericImput()` is set to 5 then the `selectInput()` may display choices only 5 choices like: 21,22,23,45,67.

Comment: Sorry I editted. Its 5. Basically this is set by the numericInput. The numbers are random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
        output$book1<-renderUI({
          numericInput("bk1", 
                       "Items in test", 
                       value = 1,
                       min = 1)
        })

        output$book10<-renderUI({
          selectizeInput(
            "bk10", "Max number of items to select", choices =1:1000,multiple =T,selected = 1,
            options = list(maxItems = input$bk1))
          #selectizeInput(
          #  "bk10", "Select Items", choices =1:1000,multiple =T,selected = 1,
          #  options = list(maxOptions = input$bk1))
        })

      }
```

For more options, you can check [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-examples.html). I hope it helps.

Comment: Not exactly , I want the numericInput to set the the max number of choices that the selectInput() can display. If it is set to 5 then the selectInput may display up to 5 choices like random 10,34,56,78,67.

Comment: It produces random numbers. I used random numbers just for example. My choices should be from 1 to 10000 but only the number set should be displayed. If this number is 10 they may be from 1 to 10, or 30 to 40 or 10 random nymbers that I will choose as I mentioned before.

Comment: I can still select more than 10 choices. Im not sure that what im asking is even possible.

Comment: So you have e.g. 100 choices but you would like to restrict the user to select only 5 or as user input in `numericInput `

Comment: that was it !tnx a lot!